# Ensuring an event loaded by jquery .load only fires once

Tags: jquery

I have a page that looks like this:

```
  <form id="NoteForm" > 
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <script>

        $(document).on("submit", "#NoteForm", function (e) {

            console.log("Submitted");
            e.preventDefault();


            $.ajax({

                url : 'Forms/Data.cfm',

                type : 'POST',

                data: $(this).serialize(), 

                success : function(data) 
                {
                    $('#Status').html(data);
                },

            });
        });

    </script>
```

It's loaded by

```
$('#ActivePage').load('NotePage.cfm);
```

When I submit the NoteForm after it has loaded, it triggers once for every time I have loaded it into ActivePage. How can I ensure it only fires one time?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `$(document).off('submit');` before `.load()` fixed this issue.